# QTextImageFormat not exported to HTML

Tags: qtextedit

I have an QTextEdit with some images and i've changed their QTextImageFormat.

But QTextEdit::toHtml() does not export their styles (loading works).

Does anybody have an idea for a workaround?

WebKit is not an option, it's an ancient Project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert the contents of `QTextDocument` to another format using [QTextBlock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#details). As the official documentation [says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#details),

> QTextBlock provides read-only access to the block/paragraph structure of QTextDocuments. It is mainly of use <...> if you want to iterate over a document and write out the contents in your own custom format.

The iteration over the contents of `QTextEdit`'s `QTextDocument` would look like this:

```
QTextEdit * editor = new QTextEdit;
<...> // fill the editor contents
QTextDocument * doc = editor->document();
for (QTextBlock currentBlock = doc->begin(); currentBlock != doc->end(); currentBlock = currentBlock.next())
{
    <...> // optionally process the block itself somehow - look at its QTextBlockFormat, for example
    for(QTextBlock::iterator it = currentBlock.begin(); !it.atEnd(); ++it) 
    { 
        QTextFragment currentFragment = it.fragment(); 
        if (currentFragment.isValid()) {
            processFragment(currentFragment); 
        }
    }
}
```

See the documentation for [QTextFragment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextfragment.html) to understand how you might implement `processFragment` from the above example.

On the other hand, you say that `WebKit` is not an option - OK but there's a replacement for it - [Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html). I have some experience of implementing a text editor with a few "advanced features" using `Qt WebEngine` as a backend and I can say it's much harder to achieve than with `Qt WebKit` but possible.